# First item in Databound CheckBoxList not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

Suppose I have an SQL table entitled "Facility" which looks like this:

```
|| FacilityID ||          Name        ||
      0             Lecture Theatre
      1             Seminar Room
      2             Computer Lab
      3             Electronics Lab
     ...                ...
```

and continues as such for 30-odd different room facilities. I'm trying to Databind these to a CheckBoxList in ASP.NET (C#) which looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="FacilityCheckList" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

The code I'm using to achieve this in C# looks like this:

```
String strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Facility";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(strSQL, DBConnection);
DBConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader FacilityData;
FacilityData = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
FacilityData.Read();
FacilityCheckList.DataSource = FacilityData;
FacilityCheckList.DataValueField = "Name";
FacilityCheckList.DataBind();
DBConnection.Close();
```

Now this works absolutely fine, apart from one thing: it doesn't display a CheckBox for the first item in the list, Lecture Theatre. Every other facility in the list shows up with a CheckBox just fine, but not Lecture Theatre - and I have no idea why!

It's not a problem on the SQL side cos when I run the query on its own, it returns the full list. And I don't think it's specific to CheckBoxList, because when I tried binding to a DropDownList instead, I got the same problem. I'm pretty much stumped as to why it is doing this, so any insight would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
FacilityData.Read();
```

This is causing the reader to move forward one notch making you lose the first item

Comment: ...thank you very much! That has solved my issue completely...thanks an awful lot, whilst I'm by no means an 'expert' at programming I've been doing it long enough to just instinctively know that it was gonna be caused by some stupid one-line thing like this :p

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Read()` on `SqlReader`. Just assign it as a datasource for your CheckBoxList after calling `ExecuteReader()`.
When you set it as a DataSource, it starts by calling Read(), and thus in your case the first record gets skipped.